# Short pipeline or long pipeline

Tags: cpu-pipelines

What is meant by a short pipeline?

Does that mean the instructions are split into small number of pieces OR length of a piece is short?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by *pieces* one means possible *stages* that the *instruction* can be split into. For example, like this "short" *[Classic RISC pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline)* with *five stages*:

- **Fetch Instruction Stage**: *Fetch* the *instruction*.
- **Decode Instruction Stage**: *Decode* the *instruction*.
- **Execute Stage**: *Execute* the *instruction*.
- **Memory Access Stage**: Access (read/write from/to) the *memory*.
- **Writeback Stage**: Write results to the *CPU registers*.

Then a **short pipeline** means that the *instruction* is split into **a low amount** of these *stages* (*pieces*), but the *amount of hardware* and *time spent* in each *stage* will actually **increase** (*length of the pieces*) compared to if there were more *stages*.